# Getting an AVG of TIMESTAMPDIFF of related table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables `features` and `responses`, where there may be multiple responses for each feature (or maybe zero responses). The responses table has a `began` and `ended` column which contain timestamps (there will be at least a began timestamp, and the ended may be NULL).

I'm trying to extract a list of `features` with summary detail of their respective responses (if any). I'm not using GROUP BY on the `responses` table as I want to include features without responses.

This is the SQL I'm trying, but it's reporting an SQL syntax error near the TIMESTAMPDIFF clause.

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, f.description, is_active, 
  (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id 
     AND r.result IS NULL) AS nr_s, 

  (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS nr_r, 

  (SELECT SUM(r.is_D) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS is_D, 

  (SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECONDS,r.began,r.ended)) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS duration

FROM features f 
WHERE f.is_deleted IS NULL AND f.id_survey=44
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – you’re not telling us _what_ error you are getting …

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SECONDS,r.began,r.ended)) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id' at line 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SECONDS` is not a valid [unit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).  You want `SECOND`:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, f.description, is_active, 
  (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id 
     AND r.result IS NULL) AS nr_s, 

  (SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS nr_r, 

  (SELECT SUM(r.is_D) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS is_D, 

  (SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,r.began,r.ended)) FROM responses r 
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id 
   WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL 
     AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     AND r.id_feature = f.id) AS duration

FROM features f 
WHERE f.is_deleted IS NULL AND f.id_survey=44
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```